# Is there an easy way to look through a directory, preview file by file, and choose to keep or delete it?

Tags: mac, photos

I'm mostly looking to do an initial pass of a folder of 10k images and I want to go through one by one and mark each for deletion or for keeping. Any easy way to do that on a mac or is there a photo organization program that will do this?

Answer (score 3):

Open the directory then instead of opening the image, you can press <kbd>space</kbd> to open a preview of that image. Now you can navigate through the images using your arrow ( <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> ) keys.

If you want to delete any one of them then just go back to finder and the same image will be selected that you were previewing.

Comment: You can actually delete the file you're currently quicklook-ing without dropping back to Finder. Best in list view.

Comment: @Tetsujin ooh. didn't know. I'll try to look up how to delete while quick-looking

Comment: Okay. Looks like the trick is to open in list view, press space to quick preview, and then press cmd + del.

Comment: Yup, quicklook is still "in the Finder" in effect, so delete works the same whether QL is open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

The Finder has four 'View' styles: Icon, List, Column, and the last one, which is either called "Cover Flow" or "Gallery View", depending on what version of OS you have.

This view lets you scroll through successive QuickLook Previews of each image in the folder.

You can select Gallery View by clicking on the icon in the Toolbar that selects the view, or using the View menu, or with <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are talking about images, here's three methods I use:

First:
Open the directory in Column view.

Minimize all the higher columns by grabbing the vertical divider and dragging it the the left.

Select the first image in the directory.  A preview appears to the right.  If it is not one you want to delete, use the down arrow until you get to one you want to delete.

Grab the column divider to the right of the preview.  Not the window edge, but the divider.  Drag it right as far as you can to make the preview bigger.  If you reach the window edge, keep going; the window edge will follow.

With the Command key pressed, click on the next image.  A preview of it will appear ***on top of*** the first one.  If it is not one you want to delete, with the Command key still pressed, click it again to de-select it.  Otherwise, leave it on the pile.

Keep going down the column that way, for each image, either keeping it on the pile or deselecting it.

When you get to the end, right-click (control-click) on one of the selected filenames and "Move to Trash."  You could also drag it to trash, but there's a risk of accidentally letting go along the way and having the whole pile end up somewhere you don't want it.

Second:

I have the program called [GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/) (**GC**).  If you want it, it is available from that link or from the app store.  I double-click an image, and GC opens it for editing.  If it is one I want to keep, I click the "Next" icon in the toolbar above the image. If I want to remove it, I use Cmd-A to select the entire image, and then Delete.  This changes the image to either transparent or all solid background color.  Then I click the "Save and next icon.  Repeat until it cycles around to the image I started with.

Then put the directory in icon view, select all the one-color images and delete them.

Third:

Make the window as big as possible.  Drag the slider in the lower left corner to make the images big enough to judge.  Select "Sort by (anything)" from the View menu.  (You need this because it brings back into the window the images that were moved out of sight by resizing.

Scroll down the window, deleting the ones you don't want.  If you find it unpleasant that they rearrange after each delete, you can instead use Cmd-click to have selections add to a collection and delete the whole collection later.